# How do I scrape my correct submissions on LeetCode?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, robots.txt

I am looking into how I can scrape my correct LeetCode submissions and upload them to Github. Being a beginner to web scraping, I read through a few blogs and I understand that we can use python libraries like BeautifulSoup, Scrapy, Selenium, etc., to perform scraping. But is it true that we can only scrape the routes which aren't disallowed in the `robots.txt` of the website ? Because Leetcode's `robots.txt` has disallowed the submissions route.

[The `robots.txt` page of leetcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZEeX.png)

If it is true that disallowed pages cannot be scraped, then is there any other way I can scrape my correct submissions ? Any advice is welcome as I am an absolute beginner here :)

P.S. An outline of the process is more than enough and I do not need the exact code. Thank You.

Comment: "If it is true that disallowed pages cannot be scraped, then is there any other way I can scrape my correct submissions ? Any advice is welcome as I am an absolute beginner here :)" It's a license issue not a possibility issue. They're _asking_ you not to scrape those solutions it's technically possible.

Comment: So if I do manage to scrape them, would my account be in trouble or anything as you say it's a license issue ?

Comment: As in they are very unlikely to but may sue you since what you are doing (downloading their content and uploading it to GitHub) may be against their terms of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is it true that we can only scrape the routes which aren't disallowed in the robots.txt of the website

Technically this is for massive indexer bots like Google, Yandex, Majestic12, etc... You're also not obligated to follow `robots.txt` but it's the nice thing to do.

Since you're not doing a massive scrape and just want your own submissions you should be fine unless you code it wrong and start DDOSing the website.

If you don't want to code it you can check GitHub for other's people code like https://github.com/world177/Leetcode-Downloader-for-Submissions which has 75 stars so it should be safe, regardless I can't guarantee its safety or suitability for your specific needs so make sure to review the repository yourself.